# Can I search for Etched Champion with Enlightened Tutor?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

Can a creature in my library with protection from all colors, like [Etched Champion](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bEtched%20Champion%5d) be the target of my search spell [Enlightened Tutor](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bEnlightened%20Tutor%5d)?

Answer (score 6):

Yes, it can; for no less than three reasons:

1. Enlightened Tutor (like all other 'search your library' cards printed so far) does not *target* a specific card in your library, so protection doesn't play a role here.
2. Protection from X only functions when a permanent is on the battlefield. (Though players can have protection from X as well.)
3. Etched Champion's Metalcraft ability only works while it's on the battlefield, so it doesn't have protection to begin with.

<sub>(not 100% sure about the third one, actually)</sub>

Comment: It's worth noting that no card that searches libraries has ever targeted, generally when cards look at hidden zones they don't target, targeting really only refers to areas like the stack, grave and battlefield. Cards that go for the hand, deck or outside the game "choose"

Comment: Right, it would be physically impossible to choose a target in a hidden zone.

Comment: #3 is true because metalcraft is a static ability, and static abilities create continuous effects while the permanent is on the battlefield (this is paraphrased). See rule 112.3d of comprehensive rules

Comment: #2 and #3 are kinda the same; the text on a card generally applies only when it's on the battlefield, unless it specifically says otherwise (for instance, you can't activate a creature's activated abilities when it's in your hand, unless it's something like cycling that obviously only applies when it's in your hand).

Comment: Re "*generally when cards look at hidden zones they don't target, targeting really only refers to areas like the stack, grave and battlefield. Cards that go for the hand, deck or outside the game "choose"*", At least one exception: [Runic Repetition](https://scryfall.com/card/isd/72/runic-repetition)

Comment: @GendoIkari, Re "*it would be physically impossible to choose a target in a hidden zone*", That's not true. In fact, there's already a mechanic that requires keeping track of a card in a hidden zone.